# How to terminate a "Loading..." program with having 3 dots using C++?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

You may have seen in many places **"Loading...**" where the 3 dots(or more), viz. "...", first appear one by one, then after displaying all the dots, they disappear  and once again appear one by one (so, total 2 times) and exit.

To elaborate:-

Stage 1:

> Loading.

Stage 2:

> Loading..

Stage 3:

> Loading...
>
> Then, it repeats second time, after that it terminates!

So, for this I prepared a C++ program and its source code is:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<dos.h>
int main()
{
    cout << "Loading";
    cout.flush();
    for (;;) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << ".";
            cout.flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        cout << "\b\b\b   \b\b\b";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program is not terminating. It doesn't stops! How can I edit this to make this terminate?

Please post codes supported by **Turbo C++ Compiler**, as I am not too much aware of the ANSI C++!!  :P

**NOTE: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION, SO DON'T MARK IT AS DUPLICATE!!!**

Thanks, in advance! :)

Comment: You have infinite loop in `for(;;)` - you need to somehow... break out when you finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

> it repeats second time, after that it terminates

Don't you need a `2` somewhere in the program in order to do that?

Perhaps somewhere right in the `for (;;)`? Similar to the other `for` in your program...

A few rhetorical questions:

- what do you think `for (;;)` does?
- why do you think that restricting one's self to Turbo C++ compiler is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `for(;;)`. Why would it terminate? Its a an endless loop.

If you want the outer loop to run only 2 times, why not `for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j){other loop}`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<dos.h>
int main()
{
    cout << "Loading";
    cout.flush();
    //The outer "for" didn't stop in your case, use this:
    for (int iterations = 0; iterations < 2; ++iterations) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << ".";
            cout.flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        cout << "\b\b\b   \b\b\b";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

1. Replace `for(;;)` with

   `for(int j=0; j < 2; ++j)
   {
       /*inner loop here*/
   }`
2. Leave `for(;;)` as is, but do the following instead:

   `int loopcount = 0;
   for(;;) /* your loop */
   {
       /* add this after inner loop */
       ++loopcount;
       if(loopcount > 1)
           break;
   }`